# Intent ACTION.IMAGE.CAPTURE with gallery on it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, permissions, android-camera

I would like to open a Camera Intent on my app but I need to see the gallery on it like Whatsapp does. I think its all about permissions but I don't know how to achieve it. 
Here is an [image of whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUpQZ.jpg) camera. There is the gallery files on the camera.

Here is my code:

```
private void addPhoto() {
    String [] perm = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);

    }else{
        Intent photo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(photo, 0);
    }

}
```

And the Manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thank you for your help and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the UI of the camera app that gets started via ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in any particular way (because you don't even know what app may get started, if the user has changed the defaults).

So this is not possible; if you need that much control over the UI, you need to build your own camera UI from scratch.

Comment: Oh, that's sad! Thank you so much!